# Vuforia, unity 3d

Tags: unity3d, vuforia

Как в качестве targeta выбрать ,например, какую-либо часть человека ? То есть при наведении на плечо на нем появлялся ваш объект ?
Буду благодарен помощи.

Comment: Можно поконкретнее, ничего не понятно

Comment: Пример: Наводишься на ладошку и на ней появляется наш анимированный объект

Comment: Такое себе пример, иди и почитай доки. Просто сделай скрипт, сделай массив геймобжектов, и метод в котором будет проверяться навелся ли кто нибудь на объект, потом узнавай, что за объект и т.д.